# Icons messed up..Please help?

Tags: pantheon, tweak-tool

Yesterday I was tweaking with my themes and icon packs. I removed some default themes and icons ( like hicolor , loginicons etc. ) . Now many icons are missing ( Network Manager icon as well ) . How to get them back ?

1.I don't want to reinstall the OS.

2.If there's an icon pack having all of the icons ( literally ) suggest me please.

3.If anyone wants to help me out please share their icons folder. ( Location of folder : /usr/share/icons )

Answer (score 3):

This will reinstall the default icons and theme:
`sudo apt install --reinstall elementary-theme elementary-icon-theme elementary-default-settings elementary-desktop`

Also try this: System Settings -> About -> Restore Default Settings

Comment: Sorry that didn't work either. It doesn't get my icons back. I have to reinstall all the apps that have missing icons.

Comment: Let's make sure that the elementary-icon-theme is enabled `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme "elementary"` and update icon cache `sudo update-icon-caches /usr/share/icons/*`